# Hadamard space: property of the Busemann function

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, geodesic

I have a question about a property of Busemann functions on Hadamard spaces.

Let $X$ be a complete CAT($0$) space. If $r:[0, \infty) \to X$ is a geodesic ray, and $x\in X$ the Busemann function is defined to be 
$$ \beta_r (x) = \lim_{t\to \infty} d(r(t), x) - t$$

Now let $\xi \in \partial X$ and let $r$ and $\sigma$ be two geodesic rays starting at $x$ and $y$ respectively with $r(\infty) = \xi = \sigma(\infty)$.

The property I try to prove is the following: for any $z \in X$

$$ \beta_r(z) = \beta_\sigma(z)- \beta_\sigma(x)$$

I have been trying for some time now, but I couldn't prove it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This holds when the level surfaces of the Busemann function for $\beta _{r}$ and $\beta _{\sigma}$ are parallel horospheres. In this case $x$ lies on the geodesic $\sigma$.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by horospheres. The above property is a simplified version of the following: If $\xi\in \partial X$, define $B_\xi (x,y) = \beta_r(x)$ where $r$ is the unique geodesic ray from $x$ to $\xi$. Property: if $\xi \in X$ and $r$ is any ray with $r(\infty) = \xi$, then $B_\xi(x,y) = \beta_r(y) -\beta_r(x)$. Am I mistaken in thinking the two statements are equivalent?

Comment: Horospheres are the level surfaces of the Busemann function i.e. a horosphere is the set $\beta^{-1}_{r}(c)$ for some real value $c$. Which $y$ in your statement, it does appear in the right side in the first equation of your comment??